# Android 6 Write permission fails to the extension SD card

Tags: android, permissions, android-external-storage

I am failing to get the Android 6 write permission to the memory extension SD card. I am getting the exception "Permission denied”. I am using Android 6, targetSdkVersion 24, with both manifest uses-permission request and run time permission request for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I am getting granted ok permission replay on the onRequestPermissionsResult().

I am able to read from this SD card but I am failing to write to it. I am using a Samsung note 4, 6.0.1. I am trying to write to the file: “/storage/3530-3464/my_file.txt”, I can read this file with the same path. I am getting exception on this line:

```
File file = new File(SD1_StoragefilePath);
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file); // get permission exception here.
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Runtime permission:**

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, 
    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
    PERMISSION_REQ_REPLAY_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Comment: Very normal. You cannot write to sd card anymore in the usual way. Only in one app specific directory reachable by getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: If you want to write to the whole SD card then use Storage Access Framework.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your help greenapps.
using the SAF as implemented:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_ACCESS);
```

I can have write access to the entire SD card.
There are two issue:

1. When implementing the intent command a funny card selection activity spears, is there a way to get read of this selection activity, and by default select the SD root.
   [Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2lzM.png)
2. On every Application start this activity spears.
   Is there a way to remember this permission granted ?